# Redirect dynamic url to static url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic

I have following type of dynamic urls.

```
http://example.com/interviews/sample1/data.xml
http://example.com/interviews/sample1234/data.xml
http://example.com/video/video-2/data.xml
```

In here interviews, sample1, sample1234, video, video-2...etc are dynamic names. 
I want to redirect those **dynamic urls** to following **static url**.

```
http://example.com/data.xml
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/.+/data.xml$ /data.xml
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data.xml$
RewriteRule /data.xml$ /data.xml [L,R]
```

Comment: Excellent. I put the RedirectMatch ^/.+/data.xml$ /data.xml 
 Worked very well. You saved my time. Thanks a lot !